# Is there a way to emulate read-write lock for Jenkins Pipeline Jobs?

Tags: jenkins, locking, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have some unset number of jobs that use resource A in a "reading" manner.
All these jobs can run concurrently just fine.

I've also have a job that "writes" to A. This job cannot run in parallel with "reader" jobs.

How would I solve this problem for Jenkins Pipelines?
Is there a way to implement simple "read-write lock"?
It looks like `lock()` can only be used to implement exclusive lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way, create multiple resources with label for example 'mylabel' (as many as many readers you have). I believe the quantity parameter [is poorly documented](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin).

Reader lock

```
lock(label: 'mylabel', quantity: 1) {
    ...
```

Writer lock - no quantity - so that's the default which is require all

```
lock(label: 'mylabel') {
    ...
```

Comment: Hm, ok, it might work, thanks. How does it interact with precedence? I.e. if writer is waiting in the "queue" while some reader holds a lock, and then a new reader job is started, will it take the lock or will it wait for writer's turn?

Comment: I think it would wait for all the resource to be free, that's a good question. If you test I would be interested in the result.

Comment: The quantity is about either a `mutex = 1` or a `semaphore > 1`... http://niclasw.mbnet.fi/MutexSemaphore.html

Comment: Hello Marcello, I'm not sure what you meant here. If no quantity is given then locked code would become a critical section - from the description you provided it's a mutex (which would mean `mutex = undefined`, as you require all the resources), where as you would switch to semaphore in the case where quantity is less than then number of resources available, let's say `n` (or less than half of the resources to be precise `semaphore < n/2`).